# love 2d Background not appearing

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to code a game in lua, but the background doesn't appear, only the "witch.png".(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A88Us.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/guH66.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlCA3.png)

I have tried putting most of my code in commentaries, changing my main.lua, nothing seems to be working

Comment: If the resolution of your background is larger than the screen, the loop will never loop thus not render.

Comment: The background and the width/height of the screen both are 1920x1080.

Comment: If you knew what you were saying you would have told me that the problem was that my first function wasn't correctly closed. The background size doesn't have anything to do with that because the loop IS to resize automatically the background.

Comment: If you would post the code as a code block instead of random linked images people may actually read your code. Also the first code is correct, not sure what error you found

Comment: I have to correct myself, since your loop starts at `0` it indeed works. It works too well however, if your background is exactly the screen size you waste 3 draw calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has been solved in the comments, but there is currently no answer posted. There are two `function love.draw()`, and the second one does not have the loop for the background. This can be easily solved by moving the loop to the second function and deleting the first function.